# What does "Use mandatory profiles on the RD Session Host server" do?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, remote-desktop-services

The description for ["Use mandatory profiles on the RD Session Host server"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee791865%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) is a little ambiguous:

> This policy setting allows you to specify whether Remote Desktop
>   Services uses a mandatory profile for all users connecting remotely to
>   the RD Session Host server.
>
> If you enable this policy setting, Remote Desktop Services uses the
>   path specified in the Set path for Remote Desktop Services Roaming
>   User Profile policy setting as the root folder for the mandatory user
>   profile. All users connecting remotely to the RD Session Host server
>   use the same user profile.
>
> If you disable or do not configure this policy setting, mandatory user
>   profiles are not used by users connecting remotely to the RD Session
>   Host server.

I have a situation where only some users need to use mandatory profiles for logging in to a Remote Desktop Session Host. If I have some users with `ntuser.dat` and some users `ntuser.man` in their roaming profile what will RD Session Host do

1. To a user who has `ntuser.man` in their roaming profile and has the setting set to `Disabled`?
2. To a user who has `ntuser.dat` in their roaming profile and has the setting set to `Enabled`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, the profile with the .man extension should behave as a mandatory user profile, regardless of the state of the Group Policy setting.

As I understand, in the second case, the user's profile (with the ntuser.dat) will be ignored and will not be used. When using this GPO, you must also configure the setting:

> Set path for Remote Desktop Services Roaming User Profile

which provides the path to a profile which will be used in preference to any other profiles related to the user (local, roaming profile on the network etc.) by all users who log on to the server.